# AM Chart - ChartScrollbar label hide or rotation possible?

Tags: charts, amcharts

I am building a line chart, everything works fine besides the labels in chartScrollbar, since the category names are a bit long, labels in cahrtScrollbar stacking onto each other make it unreadable. I'm wondering if labels can be hidden, displayed only a few or make the label rotate to a degree? [Please see below screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTt2x.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chart scrollbar does not display labels by default. If it does for you, there might one of the below:

1) You have some older version of JavaScript Charts. Upgrade to the latest one.

2) You have labels explicitly enabled by setting `autoGridCount: true` and/or `gridCount` in your `chartScrollbar` config. Remove those.

Comment: Thank you so much, autoGridCount: false did it.